# When to switch from best UX practices/guidelines to user testing?

Tags: human-interface-guideline, usability-testing

The Nielsen Norman Group has [UX Guidelines for how to present visited links](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/guidelines-for-visualizing-links/). I was adhering to the guidelines by making visited links appear faded, but the client reasoned that the users of this particular app would be repeat visitors and the styling of the visited links would be more annoying than helpful.

Is there a good way to detect when a guideline may not be appropriate for a certain context? Should you always ask another educated user about the appropriateness of following a guideline and if there is uncertainty, do a test? Or are there any guidelines that are so rock solid that you don't need to worry?

Answer (score 1):

Guidelines are just that, guidelines. They are more or less the opinion of what to do in this scenario rather than the rule. When a finding is the result of testing done by a reputable company then taking their word as truth is easier and cheaper. But if you don't agree someone's guidelines and you have support for testing then ask what it is worth to find out.

When your scenario doesn't match up closely to the one tested ask, *how different are the two and does this difference warrant further inspection?* If yes, then the cheapest next step would be to go to a colleague for a second opinion. If no, move on. The amount of effort/money you spend on a problem should be weighed against the benefit(s) of the results. In your example has their already been a test, produced by a respected company, answering the question of annoyed users and visited links. Conversely, if you don't agree with those findings, how much would it cost to test to see if changing visited links annoyed users?